# Cannot connect to server - Error 26

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

My Local server name is USER-F7A3EE0FF2\SQLEXPRESS in SQL server 20008 R2, User Id is "sa" password is also correct.
I was able to access before few hours but after restarting my system it is not accessible.

While connecting Local server in SQL server 2008 R2 an error message is coming like:
[image]

But, the remote server is accessible. what is its solution?

Comment: Is the SQL Server running in Services? can you PING that server name?

Comment: yes its running, the server name is USER-F7A3EE0FF2 and the instance is SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Can you ping the server name? go into DOS and type 

`PING USER-F7A3EE0FF2` Do you get a response?

Comment: Thanx ElectricLlama, there was a problem in the services